# How to integrate $\int e^{-(x-a)^2} \cos(bx) \, dx$?

Tags: integration, indefinite-integrals

How can I integrate the following? By the way a and b are just contants.

$$\int e^{-(x-a)^2} \cos(bx) \, dx$$

Comment: What have you tried until now? Substitution method's, integration by parts...

Comment: MathJax hint:  if you put a backslash before common functions you get the proper font and spacing, so \cos (bx) gives $\cos (bx)$

Comment: I mean I've tried expressing cos(bx) with exponentials(complex form) it seems like it's easy to integrate if the exponential function's exponent were -x^2 instead of -(x-a)^2.

Comment: Why not do $u=x-a$, then expand the result of the change to the cosine to get the same integral plus one with sine instead of cosine?  [Alpha](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=integrate+e%5E%28-%28x-a%29%5E2%29*cos%28bx%29) does your problem with the error function of complex argument

Comment: do you mean I should use cos(x+y) = cosx cosy - sinx siny ?

Comment: @FatherofChemistry: yes, one of sine/cosine will be a constant

Comment: A naive attempt would be setting $I(a)$ for the integral, then differentiating twice to see that $I''(a)=-b^2I(a)$. So $I(b)=A\cos(ab)+B\sin(ab)$. But finding the constants $A$ and $B$ could be a little bit involved, I don't know. EDIT: Well, we have
$$\int_{0}^{+\infty}\mathrm{e}^{-x^2}\cos(bx)\mathrm{d}x=\frac{\sqrt{\pi}}{2}\mathrm{e}^{-b^2}$$
so it is perhaps doable...
EDIT2: If you are looking for a general anti-derivative, then please do not read this comment!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a few ways of doing this:
$$I=\int e^{-(x-a)^2}\cos(bx)dx\tag{1}$$
we can introduce the substitution $u=x-a\Rightarrow dx=du$ to get:
$$I=\int e^{-u^2}\cos(bu+ab)du\tag{2}$$
now we can try and split this cosine up:
$$\cos(bu+ab)=\cos(bu)\cos(ab)-\sin(bu)\sin(ab)$$
now let us define the following:
$$I=\cos(ab)I_1-\sin(ab)I_2\tag{3}$$
$$I_1=\int e^{-u^2}\cos(bu)du\tag{4}$$
$$I_2=\int e^{-u^2}\sin(bu)\tag{5}$$
now we will define a new integral:
$$J=I_1+jI_2=\int e^{-u^2}e^{bju}du$$
then combine it and express it that way.

---

Alternatively you could say:
$$I=\int e^{-(x-a)^2}\cos(bx)dx=\Re\int e^{-(x-a)^2+ibx}dx$$
$$=\Re\int e^{-\left[x^2-(2a+ib)x+a^2\right]}dx=\Re\int e^{-\left[(x+(a+ib/2))^2+(iab-b^2/4)\right]}dx$$
Or you could try integration by parts, I feel like whichever way you do it could be quite messy

Answer (score 1):

Hint: assuming $a,\,b\in\Bbb R$, the integrand is$$\Re\exp[-x^2+(2a+ib)x-a^2]=\exp(b^2/4)\Re\left(\exp(iab)\exp[-(x-a-ib/2)^2]\right).$$Now substitute $y=x-a-ib/2$, then write the integral in terms of the [error function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Error_function).